# vbnet Object drag/resize code

Tags: vb.net, resize, drag

I wrote some code to drag and resize any textbox on the form while in 'dragmode' Here's a gif of what's happening instead of the textbox dragging properly,

[image: img]

Code:

```
#Region "Texbox Dragging"
    Private txt As TextBox
    Private txtptX, txtptY As Integer
    Private txtdrag As Boolean
    Private txtresize As Boolean
    Private Sub txt_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
  Me.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
    End Sub

    Private Sub txt_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
  If DragMode = True Then
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
    txtdrag = True
    txtresize = True
    txt = CType(sender, TextBox)
    txtptX = e.X : txtptY = e.Y
    End If
  End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub txt_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)

  If txtdrag = True Then
    txt.Location = New Point(txt.Location.X + e.X - txtptX, txt.Location.Y + e.Y - txtptY)
    Me.Refresh()
    txtdrag = True
  End If
  If txtresize = True Then
    txtdrag = False
    If txt.Cursor = Cursors.Cross Then
    txt.Width = e.X
    txt.Height = e.Y
    Else
    If e.X >= txt.Width - 10 Then
    txt.Cursor = Cursors.Cross
    Else
    txt.Cursor = Cursors.IBeam
    End If

    If e.Y >= txt.Height - 10 Then
    txt.Cursor = Cursors.Cross
    Else
    txt.Cursor = Cursors.IBeam
    End If
    End If
  End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub txt_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
  txt = CType(sender, TextBox)
  If txt.Cursor = Cursors.Cross Then
    txt.Cursor = Cursors.IBeam
  End If

  txtdrag = False
  txtresize = False
    End Sub
#End Region
```

I apologize for being a messy coder, but this is about attempt 12 and I am trying everything to make it work...

- they both work fine independently but I get this weird bug where I can only drag for .25 seconds when they are together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both actions (resizing and moving) cannot be performed at the same time (in the `MouseMove` method): the dragging part (the one on top) is overlapped by the resizing one. On the other hand, you don't want both actions to happen at the same time (how would the user be able to deal with resizing and relocation with just click and move?). You have to set a further condition to allow both functionalities to work in parallel; for example: double click on `txt`.

Global flag:

```
Dim nowDragging As Boolean = True
```

Double-click event assigning the right values to those:

```
Private Sub txt_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles txt.MouseDoubleClick
    nowDragging = Not nowDragging
End Sub
```

Update `MouseMove` to account for them:

```
If txtdrag = True And nowDragging Then 
'...
If txtresize = True And Not nowDragging Then
'..
```

This code performs the dragging by default; if the user double-clicks on `txt`, this functionality would be converted into resizing (and so on). This is a simple approach, just get the basic idea: enable a way to move from one functionality to the other one.

PS: nice way to show your exact problem.

Comment: I figured out how to do, I'll post my solution.

Comment: @jgetrost OK.Thanks for the award. Bear in mind that there are many alternatives, as far as the ideas are clear (not everything at the same time). I do consider this a specific solution for a specific problem (yours), but it has been nice from you to share it anyway (someone might found it useful at some point). The .gif part is certainly really good keep doing this :) (understanding what some people wants exactly is really difficult).

Answer (score 3):

I did it! After reading the code aloud to my self and following the flow, I realized that you are correct in your statement that I can not include both dragging and resizing in the MouseMove event. However :-), I can have both in the MouseDown event, and while on is occurring the other can not be triggered, It works flawlessly. Below is a .gif of the code in action, as well as the code!

.gif didn't record like I though it should, you're just gonna have to take my word for it haha.

```
#Region "Texbox Dragging"
Private txt As TextBox
Private txtptX, txtptY As Integer
Private Sub txt_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
End Sub
Dim MoveMode As Boolean
Private Sub txt_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    If DragMode = True Then
        MoveMode = True
        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
            txt = CType(sender, TextBox)
            txtptX = e.X : txtptY = e.Y
            If e.X >= txt.Width - 10 Then
                txt.Cursor = Cursors.Cross
            Else
                txt.Cursor = Cursors.IBeam
            End If

            If e.Y >= txt.Height - 10 Then
                txt.Cursor = Cursors.Cross
            Else
                txt.Cursor = Cursors.IBeam
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txt_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)

    If MoveMode = True Then
        If txt.Cursor = Cursors.Cross Then
            txt.Width = e.X
            txt.Height = e.Y
        Else
    txt.Location = New Point(txt.Location.X + e.X - txtptX, txt.Location.Y + e.Y - txtptY)
            Me.Refresh()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txt_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    txt = CType(sender, TextBox)
    If txt.Cursor = Cursors.Cross Then
        txt.Cursor = Cursors.IBeam
    End If
    MoveMode = False
End Sub
#End Region
```